# File last modified time from Android URI provided by Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-file

I need to write an Android app that observes when a file is modified by another app and then reads data from it. The file is chosen by the user. So I want to use Intent and what ever file chooser is available on the device for the user to select the file.

Doing this using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT returns a URI. I can open an InputStream and read the file into an instance of File and then check the last modified date. However, copying the file's contents into an instance of File every 5 seconds or so just to check whether it has been modified seems wasteful in terms of resources. I obviously can't use the instance of File with the data copied once from the stream to keep checking the last modified time, I'd have to keep copying it every time.

Is there a way of getting the last modified time using a URI? Or to get the actual file/absolute path using Intent? I have found some very complicated ways of getting the absolute path from a URI but they seem way too complex and I haven't found anything I'd be willing to use and feel confident it's going to work on different versions of Android.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of going through the pesky `ContentResolver` manually, you can also use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, uri).lastModified()` which uses the same code under the hood.
*Note: only works from KitKat onwards, as fromSingleUri returns `null` on earlier Android versions.*

Answer (score 3):

Note that for Android 10 onwards, you will not be able to use `file://` directly. Android is pushing for `content://` instead.

To extract the `lastModified` date from a URI after `intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`/`OPEN_DOCUMENT`/etc, you can use the `contentProvider.query()` API.

The available columns that can be extracted are [listed in `DocumentsContract.Document`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.Document)

Below is the code to extract the last update time:

```
contentResolver.query( uri, null, null, null, null  )?.use { c ->

    val dateMod: Long = try {
        val colDateModified = c
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED)
        c.moveToFirst()
        c.getLong(colDateModified)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        0
    }
    print("Date modified : $dateMod")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An update on this. I finally just decided to use this bit of code to get the absolute path to the file from URI and an instance of File from the path: https://gist.github.com/asifmujteba/d89ba9074bc941de1eaa

The reason is, that I absolutely need the last modified date of the actual file on the file system. So accessing it through an InputStream is not an option.

I haven't tested it a huge amount, but seems to be working for my purposes and on the Android API levels I've tested it.